# Прижать две кнопки к низу блока

Tags: css3, html5

```
        <div class="col-md-11 col-lg-11 col-sm-10">
            <div class="chat-meta">
                <span>
                <?=($comments['id_user']==0?$comments['name'].' (Гість з IP:'.$comments['ip'].')':'<a target="_blank" href="/user.profile.php?id='.$comments['id2'].'">'.$comments['login'].'</a>')?></span> &nbsp;<span class="pull-right"><?=gmdate('d.m.Y', $comments['time']);
                if (App::user()->group>=2){?>
                &nbsp;<button type="button" title="Видалити повідомлення" onclick="del('<?=$comments['id']?>')" class="btn btn-xs" style="color: red; font-size:10px;"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                <button type="button" title="Ban" onclick="ban('<?=$comments['ip']?>','<?=$comments['id2']?>')" class="btn btn-xs" style="color: red; font-size:10px;"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i></button>
                <?}?>
                </span>
            </div>
                <?=filter::output($comments['mess'])?>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
```

Каким образом можно опустить в правый нижний угол две кнопки botton, таким образом, чтобы они не зависи от колиства текста в самом блоке?
В css я совсем не силен :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#mainblock{
  width:300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #f34;
  position: relative;
}

#blockforbuttons{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainblock"> 
   <div id="blockforbuttons">
      <input type="button" value="Кнопка раз">
      <input type="button" value="Кнопка двас">
   </div>
</div>
```

как-то так.
Ключевой момент в том, что нам нужно свойство `position: absolute;`
Оно заставляет блок позиционироваться в указаной нами координате.
Также надо не забывать, что родительский блок должен иметь `position: relative;`